# Joins on the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, mysql-python

Is there a more efficent way to do this? I keep thinking I'm missing something. Thanks

```
SELECT DISTINCT eventId 
FROM event_tags_map 
WHERE tagId in (
    SELECT tagId FROM event_tags_map WHERE eventId=114778
) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5;
```

I'm hitting the same table twice and I'm wondering if I can get the same results faster.

Table structure:

```
mysql> describe event_tags_map;
+---------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| eventId | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| tagId   | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+---------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Indexes:

```
mysql> show index from event_tags_map;
+----------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table          | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+----------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| event_tags_map |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | eventId     | A         |      302032 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| event_tags_map |          0 | PRIMARY  |            2 | tagId       | A         |      604065 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+----------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
2 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

I looks like you will need to refer to the original table twice, one way or another.

I would recommend not using the `IN` condition, which is not very scalable and has various conter-intuitive behaviors.

My first option to use a correlated subquery with an `EXISTS` condition. This is usually the most efficient way to check that something *exists*...

```
SELECT DISTINCT eventId 
FROM event_tags_map m
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM event_tags_map m1 WHERE m1.eventId = 114778 AND m1.tagId = m.tagId
)
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5;
```

An alternative option is to use a self-`INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT eventId 
FROM event_tags_map m
INNER JOIN event_tags_map m1 ON m1.eventId = 114778 AND m1.tagId = m.tagId
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5;
```

Both solutions should be able to take advantage of a composite index on `event_tags_map(eventId, tagId)`.